# SqlDataReader not returning all rows when adding to List<MyClass>

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldatareader

I am attempting to grab some organization data from a db. I need some more data, but I am stuck at just the org name, and org address. I am attempting to perform a query that involves a join, and create an object, which is a list of a custom class I have created. The weird thing is, if I comment the code in my while loop, and just get the name of the orgs, it works, but as soon as I try to create a list of objects, it doesn't.

Here is what I've got, starting with my class:

```
namespace FFDFrameWorkPart
{
    public class OrgData
    {
        public string orgName { get; set; }
        public string orgAddress { get; set; }
    }
}

List<OrgData> OrgObject = new List<OrgData>();
List<string> orgName = new List<string>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand GrabOrgsFromDb = new SqlCommand(getConstitData, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = GrabOrgsFromDb.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                orgName.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                OrgObject.Add(new OrgData()
                {
                    orgName = reader.GetString(0),
                    orgAddress = reader.GetString(1)
                 });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            consoleLog.Value = ex.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
```

Running that code results in orgName.Count and OrgObject.Count to be in the neighborhood of 20.

If I just comment out

```
OrgObject.Add(new OrgData()
{
    orgName = reader.GetString(0),
    orgAddress = reader.GetString(1)
});
```

Then orgName.Count jumps to about 28,000. No other change to the code is necessary, just comment out where I am trying to build my list, and I lose around 28,000 records from my results.

EDIT: It's hitting a null value in one of the fields and stopping

Comment: Is there an issue in data source on column 1 of the 21st row record? It would then break the loop.

Comment: There was, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`SqlDataReader.IsDBNull`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx) to check whether the column contains non-existent or missing values.

```
OrgObject.Add(new OrgData()
{
    orgName = reader.IsDBNull(0) ? null : reader.GetString(0) ,
    orgAddress = reader.IsDBNull(1) ? null : reader.GetString(1) 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the fields are NULL and instead of using hardcoded ordinals it's better to use GetOrdinal. this way if fields are added to the table the ordinals will automatically adapt.

```
OrgObject.Add(new OrgData()
{
    orgName = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Name")) ? null : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Name")) ,
    orgAddress = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Address")) ? null : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Address")) 
);
```

or a little bit cleaner

```
int nameOrd = reader.GetOrdinal("Name");
int addressOrd = reader.GetOrdinal("Address");

    OrgObject.Add(new OrgData()
    {
        orgName = reader.IsDBNull(nameOrd) ? null : reader.GetString(nameOrd) ,
        orgAddress = reader.IsDBNull(addressOrd) ? null : reader.GetString(addressOrd));
```